# Xamarin Forms Webview

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I am currently getting the following error whenever I try to open a page from my Angular application using Xamarin.forms.view

```
04-05 20:12:17.110 W/BindingManager( 3550): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 3550[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ERROR", source: http://my-url/main.61d2d58c98366844c6a5.bundle.js (1)
```

My HybridView is being created as follow:

```
      _WebView = new UIHybridWebview
        {
            IsLocalData = false,
            Uri = "http://my-url/#/user/create",             
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

        };
```

Where UIHybridWebView is a View from Xamarin.Form.

How could I solve this problem? All solutions that I found was related to Android.Webkit, and not Xamarin.Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to make it work. The problem was not on the WebView, but on the HybridWebView. What saved me was [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91588/webview-shows-website-fine-but-custom-webviewclient-renders-site-menu-pop-ups-as-a-blank) on the official Xamarin's forum.
The solution was very simple. I just had to add the following line on the "OnElementChanged" function:

```
webView.LayoutParameters = new global::Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You Add Permission ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Yep. All internet permissions were add.

Comment: http change https

Comment: Actually the website still does not have a certificate. I realized that this error was only happening on some phones. Some other phones were working fine. Searching on internet they said that it could have something to do with jsBridge and js integration. Perhaps on some phones js is not being enabled by default. How could I change this default settings using xamarin.form.view?

Comment: You Change with WebView CustomRenderer

Comment: webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;